# Pre-populate Commerce Shipping Cart using a link

Tags: 7, commerce

I need capability to pre-populate commerce cart using a link (preferably add to the cart if one already exists).

For example a link like http://aziteez.com/cart?add_product=prod1+prod2 should add prod1 and prod2 to the existing cart of the user on my website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Rules for triggering an event on your link with [Rules link event](https://drupal.org/project/rules_linkevent) and maybe combine it with [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) to attach the link to your commerce order entities.

If you prefer to code, you'd need either to create a new menu using hook_menu or alter an existing one with hook_menu_alter and then use [commerce_cart_product_add](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_product_add/7) or [commerce_cart_product_add_by_id](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_product_add_by_id/7) to add the product to the cart user, you can retrieve the current cart from the user with [commerce_cart_order_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/7)

Comment: That looks promising. I am gonna try it out and let you know.